# Impersonalize SAP dialog user in SAP NCo application

Tags: impersonation, saprfc, sap-basis, sap-dotnet-connector

I am building a special application that helps users to insert some data in SAP. Currently the functionality of the app works as expected. But when data is saved in database, the logs are showing, that the user who made changes is the System user. I would like to request a username and password of a so called Dialog user for SAP GUI. Then the System user would impersonate it and make changes.

I tried to set User and Password parameters of RFC Configuration to Dialog users information and added RepositoryUser and RepositoryPassword parameters. This throws me an exception:

> No RFC authorization for function module RFCPING

I could make additional user authentication with `SUSR_CHECK_LOGON_DATA` RFC but this would not solve a problem of logging user changes.

Is Dialog user allowed to call remote functions, or does System user do that in his name? How to achieve impersonation in SAP .NET Connector?
I read through SAP .NET Connector 3.0 Programming Guide, but did not get the right information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your used user ID lacks the basic RFC user authorizations. Of course, you may also use a dialog user.

SAP has documented the required minimum RFC user authorizations for several usage scenarios in detail in the following note:

- [460089 - Minimum authorization profile for external RFC programs](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/460089)